# What are the technical measures of a tenor recorder?

Tags: instruments, woodwinds, recorder, instrument-making

A friend wants to make a tenor recorder from scratch (he is already a gaita maker), and asked me for the technical measures to do it, I searched through the web but couldn't found any complete reference on how to do it, its measures, etc.

So, what are the measures (in inches, cm, mm, whatsoever) of a tenor recorder?

Comment: I think your question isn't on-topic here. I'm not sure about questions about making musical instruments. You might have to spend more time doing web searches and looking for pages like this one: http://members.iinet.net.au/~nickl/tredenick/ Here's a whole list of resources: http://www.recorderhomepage.net/instruments/construction-design/  Here's a detailed diagram for an alto recorder in F: http://members.iinet.net.au/~nickl/inline/rippert_beaudin.jpg?COLLCC=2544051970&

Comment: My first port of call would be to actually obtain one, and play it a bit, whilst trying to understand why it's like it is, and could it be improved/simplified. By then, I'd have all the measurements I need. It's not going to break the bank.

Comment: Buy a cheap plastic one. They're remarkably good, and will supply all the data required.

Comment: Hard to answer: recorders date from an era, where standard pitch was not yet invented. While a=440Hz is obviously easy for playing with a piano tuned according to contemporary standards, it is noticably higher (meaning shorter) than baroque models.

Comment: I am sorry but I think everybody is a gaita maker. Do you mean gaida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a large recorder making community, with a vast and very useful [set of resources here.](http://www.recorderhomepage.net/instruments/construction-design/)

There are some links to technical plans, however a lot of them are for alto recorder rather than tenor, and even more still are stored on microfiche in libraries and not accessible online.  Having said that:

[This PDF has a graph detailing bore diameters of various tenor recorders on p8](http://www.instantharmony.net/Music/AR-01-2006.pdf)

[Another link to 3 PDF and CAD files, two with plans for soprano and one for alto recorder](http://www.bergstrom.dk/draw.html)

[A very informative website (in French and English) by a recorder maker, with a discussions on bore size and photographs of making recorders lower down on the home page under 'documents'.](http://www.flute-a-bec.com/index.html)

This is a picture of an alto recorder on top of a copy of plans by Thomas Stanesby, a maker of recorders in the 18th century, which might be useful (credit www.buyrecorders.com)

[image]

Another copy of Alto plans, this time a French design from c. 1700 (credit J.-F. Beaudin, I found it on the first link, recorderhomepage.net)

[image: http://members.iinet.net.au/~nickl/inline/rippert_beaudin.jpg?COLLCC=1497646579&]